# Maria.db Service Doest Not Start in Ubuntu. InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04, innodb

When I try to restart mariadb.service I get this error messages:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.4.12 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-04-07 19:11:55 +03; 7s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 4817 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4743 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4736 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4726 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4817 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Apr 07 19:11:55 khsbrrds01 mysqld[4817]: 2021-04-07 19:11:55 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
Apr 07 19:11:55 khsbrrds01 mysqld[4817]: 2021-04-07 19:11:55 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Apr 07 19:11:55 khsbrrds01 mysqld[4817]: 2021-04-07 19:11:55 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Apr 07 19:11:55 khsbrrds01 mysqld[4817]: 2021-04-07 19:11:55 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Apr 07 19:11:55 khsbrrds01 mysqld[4817]: 2021-04-07 19:11:55 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
Apr 07 19:11:55 khsbrrds01 mysqld[4817]: 2021-04-07 19:11:55 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
Apr 07 19:11:55 khsbrrds01 mysqld[4817]: 2021-04-07 19:11:55 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Apr 07 19:11:55 khsbrrds01 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 07 19:11:55 khsbrrds01 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 07 19:11:55 khsbrrds01 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.4.12 database server.
```

How can I fix this issue? Os: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: So is ibdata1 writable? If not why not?

Comment: When I look with "ls -l" it shows writable ```-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 79691776 Apr  5 16:25 ibdata1``` @A.B

Comment: No idea. If you know you changed something from default just tell it.